# Polling or event based resize detection in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, backbone.js, timer

So I'm considering two ways of getting a Backbone view to to fire an event when it is resized.

The first is using polling, perhaps through jquery's resize plugin.

The second is leveraging this plugin - https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize, which uses the approach in this http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/.

My question is about performance. Jquery's plugin (I think) uses polling with timers, meaning that for every element (and suppose there are a lot), we need to poll for changes to every view's element. The other method does not do this and has an extra DOM element for every view.

Which would be more performant in terms of speed? Suppose I have a lot of views, which will be the better method to use?

Comment: What is wrong with [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) ?

Comment: @Tomanow AFAIK `resize` event is only fired on `window`, not every element